# How to run Spring batch project in SpringSource Tool Suite

Tags: spring-batch

First,I'm trying to learn Spring-batch,I have an completed Spring-batch project.Launch this project need start_up.sh in linux platform,but how to run it in SpringSource Tool Suite? What arguments need add to run configurations?

Second,If I want to run an separate job, how to configure?

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

I have a hard time understanding your question, but I try to answer nevertheless:

- I assume you are talking about the startup.sh which is used to start Tomcat. If this is the case, you probably have a web project, so it can be deployed in STS to Tomcat or Springsource tc Server. Just click on the project and drag it to either of them in the Servers tab. (Or right click on any of them and then Add/Remove...)
- This one is even more just a shot in the dark: use 
  `java org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner testJob.xml testJob` where testJob.xml is the one containing the definition of your job and testJob is the name of it.